# Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIDocumentPickerDelegate' swift 2

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIDocumentPickerDelegate'. I can't get the UIDocumentPickerDelegate to allow it to conform. Can someone help and explain how I can fix this. Swift always does this.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func importFiles(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        var documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.image"], inMode: UIDocumentPickerMode.Import)

        documentPicker.delgate = self

        documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen

        self.presentedViewController(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func documentPicker(controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAtUrl url: NSURL){

        if (controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerMode.Import){

            self.imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.path!)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same compile error while my deployment target was iOS 7.1. The reason you're probably getting this error is because UIDocumentPickerDelegate is only available for iOS 8 and higher. Also you have misspelled delegate property assigning and self.presentedViewController(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 0):

I revised your information on this link that has a similar problem.

[Cannot conform to STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate since Xcode 8 GM on Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381210/cannot-conform-to-stpaddcardviewcontrollerdelegate-since-xcode-8-gm-on-swift-3)

The problem is the swift compiler than can´t recognize automatically some information. So in this case:

didPickDocumentAt url: URL

Then i follow the problem to this link:

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2596

In this link the information is that Swift 3 mistake data types, so i research some more and get to this page. The mistaken type in this case is "URL".

Then the solution is in the same page. I write it bellow:

```
weak var delegate : UIDocumentPickerDelegate?

@available(iOS 8.0, *)
public func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: Foundation.URL ){
    //
    print("algo")
}
```

To that matter i reproduce the error in my computer, it is caused when diferent imported libraries has the same definition for data types, in this case URL type, which Swift 3 doesnt recognize automatically neither tells correctly the error. So it has to be defined directly.