# Cannot conform to STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate since Xcode 8 GM on Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, stripe-payments, swift3

Since converting my codebase to swift 3 with Xcode 8 GM, I get this error when trying to conform to the `STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate` (Stripe SDK). I'm very surprised by this error because even when stubbing those methods automatically with Xcode I encounter the same error. Types seem to match, no idea what's going on.

```
extension ViewController: STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate {

    func addCardViewControllerDidCancel(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController) {
    }

    func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreateToken token: STPToken, completion: STPErrorBlock) {
    }
}
```

Generates this error

```
Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate'

Protocol requires function 'addCardViewController(_:didCreateToken:completion:)' with type '(STPAddCardViewController, STPToken, STPErrorBlock) -> Void'; do you want to add a stub?

Candidate has non-matching type '(STPAddCardViewController, STPToken, (Error?) -> Void) -> ()'
```

Here's the definition of the protocol

```
public protocol STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    public func addCardViewControllerDidCancel(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController)
    public func addCardViewController(_ addCardViewController: STPAddCardViewController, didCreateToken token: STPToken, completion: Stripe.STPErrorBlock)
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of investigation from @AliSoftware and @bdorfman in the related [Stripe SDK issue](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/issues/437), it's been found that adding the `@escaping` attribute to the `completion` param fixes the issue.

It seems to be a compiler & stubbing issue on swift's end, that is currently tracked here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2596.