# Swift 3: fix issue Type "className" does not conform to protocol 'UIDocumentPickerDelegate'

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8, icloud

I'm migrating my code from Swift 2 to Swift 3 but my code throws this error: Type "className" does not conform to protocol 'UIDocumentPickerDelegate'. I've migrate many parts of my document as you can see but error stills,

```
extension className: UIDocumentMenuDelegate {
    //Opening the Document Menu
    func documentMenu(_ documentMenu: UIDocumentMenuViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        print ("documentMenu")
        self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func documentMenuWasCancelled(_ documentMenu: UIDocumentMenuViewController) {

    }
}
//Using UIDocumentPickerDelegate, error persists here.
extension className: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {

    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
        if(controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerMode.import){
          print ("success")
        }
    }

}

class className: BaseViewController{

...Tons of code here...

    @IBAction func importKeyButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: ["public.data","public.text","public.content"], in: UIDocumentPickerMode.import)
    var documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.txt"], in: UIDocumentPickerMode.import)
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
    self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

How can I solve it?, I've use all methods that procotol requires. Thanks

Comment: I don't know the issue, but if you want to conform to **suggested** Swift conventions, your class name should be "ClassName", not "className".

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. No error messages on the extension conforming to `UIDocumentPickerDelegate`. Please provide enough info to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Does your BaseViewController inherit from UIViewController?

Comment: @dfd I've done it right, thanks :D. Problem stills

Comment: @RyanH. Yes, it does.

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

}

Answer (score -1):

I revised your information on this link that has a similar problem.

[Cannot conform to STPAddCardViewControllerDelegate since Xcode 8 GM on Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381210/cannot-conform-to-stpaddcardviewcontrollerdelegate-since-xcode-8-gm-on-swift-3)

The problem is the swift compiler than can´t recognize automatically some information. So in this case:

didPickDocumentAt url: URL

Then i follow the problem to this link:

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2596

In this link the information is that Swift 3 mistake data types, so i research some more and get to this page. The mistaken type in this case is "URL".

Then the solution is in the same page. I write it bellow:

```
weak var delegate : UIDocumentPickerDelegate?

@available(iOS 8.0, *)
public func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: Foundation.URL ){
    //
    print("something")
}
```

To that matter i reproduce the error in my computer, it is caused when diferent imported libraries has the same definition for data types, in this case URL type, which Swift 3 doesnt recognize automatically neither tells correctly the error. So it has to be defined directly.

Comment: Thanks for posting in Spanish! That answer solved my problem. Greetings

Comment: Hi Jose, @Elizabeth! Just wanted to let you know that we now have a Spanish-language version of Stack Overflow, if you've any interest in such a thing: http://es.stackoverflow.com/